# How to configure automapper so that it won't override the properties which are not defined in mapping

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-core, automapper

I am mapping one class property with two different other classes using auto mapper like below code:

```
var emp = map.Map<EmployeeAddressDto, Employee>(employeeAddressDto);
```

The above mapping gives me objects like the below:

```
Address1 = "some xyz address1"
Address2 = "some xyz address2"
Phone = "0000000000"
```

and then mapping the output object with `EmployeeOtherAddressDto`

```
map.Map<EmployeeOtherAddressDto, Employee>(emp);
```

The above mapping changes my out to this:

```
Address1 = "some other xyz address1"
Address2 = "some other xyz address2"
Phone = null
```

But I want it to be like the below:

```
Address1 = "some other xyz address1"
Address2 = "some other xyz address2"
Phone = "0000000000"
```

When the above mapping occurs it makes the phone no null but I want it to remain as it was defined on the previous mapping, although I want to override `Address1` and `Address2` fields.

Here is my mapping:

```
CreateMap<EmployeeAddressDto, Employee>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.Address1, options => options.MapFrom(src => src.Address1))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.Address2, options => options.MapFrom(src => src.Address2))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.Phone, options => options.MapFrom(src => src.Phone))
                .ValidateMemberList(MemberList.None)
                .ForAllMembers(opts => opts.Condition((src, dest, srcMember) => srcMember != null));


CreateMap<EmployeeOtherAddressDto, Employee>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.Address1, options => options.MapFrom(src => src.Address1))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.Address2, options => options.MapFrom(src => src.Address2))
                .ValidateMemberList(MemberList.None)
                .ForAllMembers(opts => opts.Condition((src, dest, srcMember) => srcMember != null));
```

I want to do this in my mapping profile because I am using it in many places and do not want to update the phone no without using a mapper.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this method for config your mapping.

> AfterMap<>()

```
 CreateMap<EmployeeOtherAddressDto, Employee>().AfterMap<EmployeeMappingAction>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.Address1, options => options.MapFrom(src => src.Address1))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.Address2, options => options.MapFrom(src => src.Address2))                    
                .ValidateMemberList(MemberList.None)
```

you can check your filed after mapping to check is it null or not.

```
public class EmployeeMappingAction: IMappingAction<EmployeeOtherAddressDto,Employee>
{
    public void Process(EmployeeOtherAddressDto source, Employee destination, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        if (source.Phone == null)
        {
            destination.Phone = "";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't want to make the make phone null. I want it to be remain as it is

Comment: Do you check **Ignore()** method ? 
                _.ForPath(q => q.Phone, q => q.Ignore());_

Comment: I tried but not working

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75614450/11436055   
Please check this link, it seems is same problem.