# AutoMapper resets undefined parts(from source) in an already filled destination class's nested list element

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, automapper

Source

```
public class MaterialDto {
    public int MaterialId { get; set; }
    public List<MaterialLocaleDto> Locales{ get; set; }
}

public class MaterialLocaleDto {
    public int MaterialLocaleId { get; set; }
    public string MaterialLocaleText { get; set; }
}
```

Destination

```
public class MaterialEntity {
    public int MaterialId { get; set; }
    public List<MaterialLocaleEntity> Locales{ get; set; }
}

public class MaterialLocaleEntity {
    public int MaterialLocaleId { get; set; }
    public string MaterialLocaleText { get; set; }
    public int CriteriaId { get; set; } //Only different
}
```

I'm trying to update my entity in C# with EF Core and Automapper.

First I'm getting my destination object from db by source's id like this

```
MaterialEntity destObj = _contex.get(command.MaterialId);
/* Here my destObj as json to show what is inside
destObj = {
  "MaterialId": 1,
  "Locales": [
    {
      "MaterialLocaleId": 1,
      "MaterialLocaleText": "Some Text",
      "CriteriaId": 1
    },
    {
      "MaterialLocaleId": 2,
      "MaterialLocaleText": "Some other text",
      "CriteriaId": 1
    }
  ]
}
*/
```

And then I'm trying to map my source object which is come from ui.

```
_mapper.Map(MaterialDto,MaterialEntity);
```

But because of my (source) `MaterialLocaleDto` doesn't have `CriteriaId` definition set 0 in the destination. Final state of the `destObj`:

```
destObj = {
  "MaterialId": 1,
  "Locales": [
    {
      "MaterialLocaleId": 1,
      "MaterialLocaleText": "Some Text Came From Dto",
      "CriteriaId": 0 //I don't want to reset here 
    },
    {
      "MaterialLocaleId": 2,
      "MaterialLocaleText": "Some Other Text Came From Dto",
      "CriteriaId": 0 //I don't want to reset here 
    }
  ]
}
```

It works on the base object when I don't want to reset undeclared variables. But it resets on the nested list object.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Check [the execution plan](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Understanding-your-mapping.html).

Comment: Did you find a solution to this issue, i'm having similar problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Automapper.Collection.EntityframeworkCore 9.0 Library solved my problem.

When I adeded to program.cs to this code below:

```
collection.AddAutoMapper(cfg => {
        cfg.AddCollectionMappers();
    }, typeof(MyProfile));
```

And then managed my mappig profile like this:

```
CreateMap<MaterialLocaleDto, MaterialLocaleEntity>().ReverseMap()
.EqualityComparison((sir, si) => sir.MaterialLocaleId == si.MaterialLocaleId );
```

Problems solved. Its just updating if there is a match with id. Or else creating. This is what exactly I want.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the property *CriteriaId* to be mapped, you can add the method *Ignore()* for that member in your mapping file profile.

Comment: CriteriaId is not declared on the source so even I tried ignore it still resets